# How to avoid the Conflicting getter definitions for property with same attribute name with different datatype

Tags: java, spring, jackson, fasterxml

Is there any way to avoid the Conflicting getter definitions for property "memory" where it is generated in runtime where we cannot change the strucutre,

```
{
"memory": "not_available"
}

{
"memory": {
    "data1": 0,
    "data2": 2,
}
}
```

I have 1 properties with different data type and how to handle the scenario's where I am using fasterxml api

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "memory"
})

public class MyMemoryData{
     @JsonProperty("memory")
     private Memory memory;

     @JsonProperty("memory")      
     private String memoryValue;
     }
```

Getting the below Exception Conflicting getter definitions for property "memory":

Comment: That's a very bad design to have 2 attributes with same name.

Comment: I understand but this design cannot be changed where it is auto-generated from a server and so need a solution to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you really need two different fields for the "memory" field? I mean, are you able to use only private Memory memory; and set null if it is "not_available"?

If yes ("not_available" == null), you can write your custom Jackson deserializer for the memory field, which will implement logic: if the value is "not_available", returns null, else parse the object.

Comment: Are you highlighting to use the below ,
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "memory"
})

public class MyMemoryData{
     @JsonProperty("memory") 
    ("not_available" == null)
     private Memory memory;
}

Comment: Yes, I don't know your use case exactly, but it looks like valid

`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) @JsonPropertyOrder({ "memory" }) public class MyMemoryData{ @JsonProperty("memory") private Memory memory; // null if 'not_available' } `